# Error: ERROR: The returned value is not a convertible string:

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to return a struct of contract details when I input the contract deployed address. When I test in remix is seems to return the struct, however now I'm trying on the JS side I get an error.

I'm new to this so any input is much appreciated!

return value in Remix:

```
campaginDetails

uint256 
0: string: description neo
1: uint256: minimumContribution 100
2: string: campaignCategory protcol
3: string: endDate 20180312
4: address: managerAddress 0xcaed1558cf61b4305bf9b5d7b74172bb56
```

Error:

```
Error: ERROR: The returned value is not a convertible string:
```

Smart Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract CampaignFactory {

    address[] public deployedCampaignsAddress;
    address[] public managersAddress;

    function createCampaign(string description, uint minimumContribution, string campaignCategory, string endDate) public {
        Campaign newlyCreatedCampaign = new Campaign(description, minimumContribution, campaignCategory, endDate, msg.sender);
        deployedCampaignsAddress.push(newlyCreatedCampaign);
        managersAddress.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function getDeployedCampaigns() public view returns (address[]) {
        return deployedCampaignsAddress;
    }

    function getManagersAddress() public view returns (address[]) {
        return managersAddress;
    }
}

contract Campaign {

    struct NewCampaignType {
        string description;
        uint minimumContribution;
        string campaignCategory;
        string endDate;
        address managerAddress;
    }

    struct Request {
        string description;
        uint value;
        address recipient;
        bool complete;
        uint approvalCount;
        mapping(address => bool) approvals;
    }

    NewCampaignType[] public campaignDetails;
    Request[] public requests;
    mapping(address => bool) public approvers;
    uint public approversCount;
    address public currentManager;

    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == currentManager);
        _;
    }

    function Campaign(string description, uint minimumContribution, string campaignCategory, string endDate, address managerAddress) public {
        NewCampaignType memory createCampaign = NewCampaignType({
            description: description,
            minimumContribution: minimumContribution,
            campaignCategory: campaignCategory,
            endDate: endDate,
            managerAddress: managerAddress
        });
        campaignDetails.push(createCampaign);
    }

    function contribute() public payable {
        require(msg.value > campaignDetails[0].minimumContribution);
        approvers[msg.sender] = true;
        approversCount++;
    }

    function createRequest(string description, uint value, address recipient) public restricted {
        Request memory newRequest = Request({
           description: description,
           value: value,
           recipient: recipient,
           complete: false,
           approvalCount: 0
        });

        requests.push(newRequest);
    }

    function approveRequest(uint index) public {
        Request storage request = requests[index];

        require(approvers[msg.sender]);
        require(!request.approvals[msg.sender]);

        request.approvals[msg.sender] = true;
        request.approvalCount++;
    }

    function finalizeRequest(uint index) public restricted {
        Request storage request = requests[index];

        require(request.approvalCount > (approversCount / 2));
        require(!request.complete);

        request.recipient.transfer(request.value);
        request.complete = true;
    }

    function getSummary() public view returns (
      uint, uint, uint, uint, address
      ) {
        return (
          campaignDetails[0].minimumContribution,
          this.balance,
          requests.length,
          approversCount,
          campaignDetails[0].managerAddress
        );
    }

    function getRequestsCount() public view returns (uint) {
        return requests.length;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
class CampaignIndex extends Component {
  //getInitialProps used to fetch data exclusively with next.js  regular react uses
  // componentDidMount()
  static async getInitialProps() {
    const deployedCampaignsAddress = await factory.methods
      .getDeployedCampaigns()
      .call();
    console.log(deployedCampaignsAddress);
    const campaignsManagerAddress = await factory.methods
      .getManagersAddress()
      .call();
    const campaignsDetails = await campaign(deployedCampaignsAddress[0])
      .methods.campaginDetails(deployedCampaignsAddress[0])
      .call();
    console.log('this');
    console.log(campaignsDetails);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are following the same tutorial on Udemy - make sure you update requests in campaigns/requests/index.js as follows:

```
const requests = await Promise.all(     
    Array(parseInt(requestCount)).fill().map((element, index) => {         
        return campaign.methods.requests(index).call()    
       })
);
```